# displaying font which is not defined on the client side , just on the server

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm now building a new website that provides SMS services using *clickatell* .this site have many fonts families that are not defined on the client side , for example if I open the site from other computer the font will display as  the default . I have  learned the `font-face` in `CSS` ; but it is not working > here is my simple test code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <style> 
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'oswald_stencilregular';
            src: url('/protected/extensions/Fonts/oswald/Oswald-Light.otf');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div style='font-family:oswald_stencilregular'>
            give me my font 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

See, it is simple code but the test `"give me my font"` will not be shown with this type of  font; I have installed the font and I made a path to the font as you can see from the code. I have tested the path from other `php` file and it is working, I have  made many researches but still the same problem, which is why this declaration for this font is not working, is there another way to declare a font on the server side so the client will not care if he has this type of font and his computer and he will display the font as declared on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single font format that works on all browsers. To circumvent this, you usually add in multiple font formats for each font you need. The CSS for that looks something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BMR';
    src: local('blissmediumregular');
    src: url('/fonts/blissmedium-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/blissmedium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/blissmedium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/blissmedium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/blissmedium-webfont.svg#blissmediumregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You could also try using a Font Generator tool like [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to get the different font types needed.

Comment: i got it , so i have to defined several types to different browsers .thanks , i will go to the font squirrel

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your `style` declaration uses double quotes (ie: `style="font-family:oswald_stencilregular;"`

Second, be aware that [each browser uses a different font format](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/02/the-font-face-rule-revisited-and-useful-tricks/). Unless you are testing in Safari 3.2+ or Firefox, your browser needs a different font format like .woff or .ttf or .svg.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cross browser `font-face` that I've used in many projects and it works just fine:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "YOURFONT";
  src: url('path-to/font.eot?#') format('eot'),  /* IE6–8 */
       url('path-to/font.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
       url('path-to/font.ttf') format('truetype');  /* Saf3—5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}
```

However, you have to test some other stuffs: 1. Does your server support the `mime-type` of your font? 2. Which browser are you testing?

Answer (score 0):

some hosting servers does not support font-styles as in Windows Servers you need to add an .otf mime-type to it so it would allow the font-face to work properly.

Are you using a Windows Server?

Comment: but i dont understand hot to add .otf mime-type ??

Comment: this type depends on the font type you are using Oswald-Light.otf but since you are using WAMP, there is no need for this, you need to check your stylesheet for errors.

Comment: Actually, the presence of a WAMP stack doesn't matter at all. It's the client's browser that requires a certain type of font format.

Comment: @khalidjarrah

fix your style:

<div style="font-family: 'oswald_stencilregular';">
     give me my font 
</div>